# What to push as arguments for Node head in Sorted Insert(sortedIn() method) in Singly Linked List in java

Tags: java, sorting, arguments, parameter-passing

I have passed a parameter 'head' to my sortedIn method which inserts in a sorted manner in a linked list, and geeks4geeks states it as, we have to pass the head as a parameter to this function.
I did so, but then I don't know how and what do I pass in the main method as argument for the sortedIn method.
Here is the code attached... And kindly excuse me if I haven't followed any rule as this is my first question here.

```
// EZ reference problems at method from line 69 and argument passing at line 160... 
// Have always faced an issue where we are to pass arguments like this
class LL {
    Node head;
    private int size;

    class Node {
        int data;
        Node ref;
        Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.ref = null;
            size++;
        }
    }
    public void push(int data) {
        Node newnode = new Node(data);
        if (head == null) {
            head = newnode;
            return;
        }
        newnode.ref = head;
        head = newnode;
    }
    public void append(int data) {
        Node newnode = new Node(data);
        if (head == null) {
            head = newnode;
            return;
        }
        Node curr = head;
        while (curr.ref != null) {
            curr = curr.ref;
        }
        curr.ref = newnode;
    }
    public void insert(int data, int pos_data) {
        Node newnode = new Node(data);
        if (head == null) {
            head = newnode;
            return;
        }
        Node curr = head;
        while (curr.ref != null) {
            if (curr.data == pos_data)break;
            curr = curr.ref;
        }
        newnode.ref = curr.ref;
        curr.ref = newnode;
    }
    public void inatp(int data, int p) {
        Node newnode = new Node(data);
        if (head == null) {
            head = newnode;
            return;
        }
        Node curr = head;
        if (p == 1) {
            newnode.ref = head;
            head = newnode;
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < p-2; i++){
            curr = curr.ref;
        }
        newnode.ref = curr.ref;
        curr.ref = newnode;
    }
    // Here is the sortedInsert method where i have pushed Node head as parameter but am confused to as what to pass as argument!!!
    public Node sortedIn(Node head, int data) {
        Node newnode = new Node(data);
        if (head == null) {
            head = newnode;
            return newnode;
        }
        else if (head.ref == null) {
            newnode.ref = head;
            head = newnode;
            return newnode;
        }
        else {
            Node curr = head;
            while (curr.ref != null && curr.ref.data < data) {
                curr = curr.ref;
            }
            newnode.ref = curr.ref;
            curr.ref = newnode;
            return head;
        }
    }
    public void delf() {
        if (head == null) return;
        size--;
        if (head.ref == null) {
            head.ref = null;
        }
        head = head.ref.ref;
    }
    public void dell() {
        if (head == null) return;
        size--;
        if (head.ref == null) {
            head = null;
            return;
        }
        Node curr = head;
        while (curr.ref!=null) {
            if (curr.ref.ref == null)break;
            curr = curr.ref;
        }
        curr.ref = null;
    }
    public void delm(int pos) {
        if (head == null) return;
        size--;
        if (head.ref == null) {
            head = null;
            return;
        }
        Node curr = head;
        while (curr.ref != null) {
            if (curr.ref.data == pos) break;
            curr = curr.ref;
        }
        curr.ref = curr.ref.ref;
    }
    public int find(int posdata) {
        int c = 0;
        Node curr = head;
        while (curr!= null) {
            if (curr.data == posdata) return c;
            curr = curr.ref;
            c++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public void size() {
        System.out.println(size);
    }
    public void p() {
        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("Empty");
            return;
        }
        Node curr = head;
        while (curr != null) {
            System.out.print(curr.data + "==>");
            curr = curr.ref;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LL l = new LL();
        l.push(1);
        l.push(2);
        l.append(3);
        l.p();
        System.out.println(l.find(1));
        l.inatp(4, 4);
        l.p();
        l.sortedIn(????, 5); // what do i push as argument for sortedIn method as Node head parameter's argument?
    }
}
```

Comment: in this example you should pass ll.head as argument instead of "????"

Comment: In general this example looks like it should be written in several classes (files) main should be in one file, Node class in another, sortedIn method in some util class etc. Then it makes sense. In your example there is no need to pass head to sortedIn method at all. Since you can access it from main scope